# Is "information and data" a redundant duplet in this context?

Tags: phrases, pleonasms

I understand information and data are not the same.

Here are the two main differences I have found:

- Data are items of information ([Data on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data))
- Data are collected for reference or analysis ([Data on Oxford Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/data)), while information may but needs not be collected, it can just be learned ([Information on Oxford Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/information))

Therefore it seems that "data" is a hyponym of information characterised by being discrete items collected for a purpose.

Sometimes data is also said to be a "source" of information, although I am not convinced by this explanation as it seems to convey a subjective concept of information. I'm not denying such usage but I find more useful to think about information as something objectively present in many forms (data being one of them), whether it is used by somebody or not. In this view, data is not a source of information, it is information.

So in my understanding, for most practical purposes, data is a form of information, and therefore the following duplet is redundant:

> to guarantee the confidentiality of information and data

and can be safely avoided by just saying

> to guarantee the confidentiality of information

Would you agree or am I missing something?

Comment: I think a document could use the words *information* and *data* in different senses, which it might make clear before the statement about confidentiality. Then, it might make sense to refer to both terms.

Comment: In IT circles, *data* is any little piece that may or may not add up to usefulness -  hence data processing. After processing, *information* is that collection of useful data. Not here, but there are many times we use a pair for emphasis (two language sources common): kith and kin, hale and hearty, part and parcel.

Comment: I was taught that data are without meaning or context but information is data with meaning and context. For instance the numbers 24, 10, 07 could be data in row of a table and, without the column identifiers, are meaningless. However if the columns are identified as 'birth day', 'birth month' and 'birth year' or 'student id', 'school year' and 'year ranking' they become information. It is, thus, possible for a set of data to include items which have been analysed and some which have not. There will, therefore, be both data in the set and information derived from it.

Comment: Are you certain it’s not a legal thing, where language has meaning that may differ from that in more general contexts?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of context. Yes, it is a confidentiality clause in a legal agreement, but there are no legal definitions and no prior uses in different senses. And because it is legal I find it hard to imagine one could say: "I published the data but it wasn't confidential because it was unprocessed, without meaning". The distinction here seems unnecessary. It may have the function to make the reader associate confidentiality to a broader range of things at the moment of reading, but eventually would end up meaning the same. Does that make it a duplet?